# Eloqua Forms: how to show/hide fields depending on others fields

Tags: forms, hide, show, eloqua

#### Eloqua Forms

I want to know if there is some way to **show or hide fields** (or sections) depending on what values of others fields.

Of course, I am asking on some OOTB behavior; if not, will do it with JS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Eloqua does not have a conditional rules for form field visibility (at least not yet. [Dependent Field Visibility/Logic](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/11485)).

Until that functionality is brought into Eloqua Forms, you would have to write some Javascript to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks guy.

And what do you think about this: https://relationshipone.com/blog/progressive-profiling-oracle-eloqua/

Comment: @korbo , Been quite some time since I've logged in :'( But that's Progressive Profiling. It doesnt show/hide fields based on field values, It mostly hides the fields/section if there is a value for them. While it is a great feature for forms, based on your question, I don't think that's what you're looking for. You can read more about it in the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAA/#Help/Forms/ProgressiveProfiles.htm%3FTocPath%3DForms%7CProgressive%2520profiles%7C_____0)

Comment: Thanks @user1234567 !

Actually, I had posted other question for Progressive Profiling!

Pleas check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182677/eloqua-forms-progresive-profie-profiling

For some reason, it's not working. If you can reach me at mateo.recoba@gmail.com, would be very nice!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You would need a listener (onchange in example).

Eloqua uses dynamic ids for form field elements based upon order. Setting the "HTML Name" value for the fields in the form editor allows for a more stable reference.

```
var fieldToListenTo = document.getElementsByName('eloquaHTMLName1')[0];
var fieldToChange = document.getElementsByName('eloquaHTMLName2')[0];

fieldToListenTo.onchange = function(){
  if(fieldToListenTo == 1) {
    fieldToChange.value = "New Value 1";
  }
  else {
    fieldToChange.value = "New Value 2";
  }
}
```