# Eloqua Forms - Progresive Profie / Profiling

Tags: profiling, profile, progressive, eloqua

I'm quite new in Eloqua. I'm trying to generate Progressive Profiling Forms, and as I can find in the web, there are two ways: Adding Rules, or setting Stages or Linear flow. But, I am not being able to do either.

Any help?

By the way, the most I could progress, is: click on Progressive Profile button, add some fields, then copy/paste HTML+JS generated, and open the form in Chrome (the whole code seems to be complete auto-sufficent). But there are many weird behaviors...

Answer (score 2):

The way progressive profiling form works is:
Form Fields where contact data is populated using [Field Merges](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAA/index.html#Help/FieldMerges/FieldMerges.htm%3FTocPath%3DComponents%7CField%2520merges%7C_____0) are hidden. Form fields which do not have a value (or if the field merge could not populate a value) are displayed for the submitter to provide.

This means that each time a contact provides some information, This data is captured and hidden, so that the next visit (or a visit to a different page) will display a different set of fields

Quoting [one article](https://www.relationshipone.com/blog/progressive-profiling-oracle-eloqua/) (This is the same link you provided on an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649641/eloqua-forms-how-to-show-hide-fields-depending-on-others-fields))

> As the contact comes back to get more information from you,
>   progressive profiling allows you to ask them for more and equally
>   important, new, information about themselves. You get to know them
>   better over time all the while making it easy for them to get what
>   they want. Then, like any form data collected, this information can be
>   used to enable lead scoring, persona development and predictive
>   analysis modeling.

- The first run will show a small set of fields (this is configured manually on the Eloqua forms)
- When the same contact enters another webpage with a similar form, on the same browser as before (This is essential), the earlier fields are hidden and a new set of fields are displayed.
- In other words, with each visit fields which are pre-populated with contact data are hidden from view and only the fields that do not have a value are displayed.

**Note**

- For Progressive Profiling to work, The browser must have cookies enabled, and the form fields must have a Field Merge
- Progressive Profiling does not work on a local html. It has to be on a Landing Page or a website with Eloqua tracking
- The Progressive profiling behavior is different, if your page domains are different (example1.com and example2.com for instance)

**Additional References**

- You can refer to Oracle's documentation for further details on this. For configuring Progressive Profile on Eloqua forms, you can refer the links below
- [Adding a Progressive Profile](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAA/Help/Forms/Tasks/AddingaProgressiveProfile.htm) - This mode will just list x fields that do not have values. The x would have to be manually added into Eloqua
- [Configuring a progressive profile in staged mode](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAA/Help/Forms/Tasks/ConfiguringProgressiveProfileInStagedMode.htm) - This will display a group of fields rather than just going one field after another
- You can also refer to [Oracle Communities](https://community.oracle.com/community/topliners) where you will get a more concise response from Eloqua users, if not Consultants from Oracle
- When searching communities, you might be some across articles about a Progressive Profiling Cloud Component, this component was discontinued in 2017

Comment: Wow, amazing response! Thanks a lot! So... brief questions.

1 - This behavior, is only applied to the field within Progressive Profile section (sky-blue colored)

2 - You said that we need to configure in Eloqua, which "small set of fields" will show. Where and how to do that? (in both cases, List and Stages).